# Can I download a users FB photos to match information to them?

Tags: iphone, facebook, image-recognition, face-recognition

I've been scouring the internet but haven't been able to find a good answer.

**THE SCENARIO**

I'm in the midst of checking policies for an app where if I take a photo (using an iphone, android, anything...) of a FB friend (who I'm currently standing in front of), I can find out my FB friends name and other helpful information to lead a conversation.

(In other words, help me remember a friends name who I've forgotten who i currently have as a facebook friend).

**WHY**

I'd rather not run into any privacy or data issues and figure if this is doable before I spend a bit of time and money developing such an app.

I know google prohibits this...
[image: Google Anti Cross Reference Policy]

**HOW FB WOULD BE INTEGRATED**

I'd develop my own or use another facial recognition API to do the actual comparing of my friends photos to the photo I just took. That being said I imagine that the app would download a couple photos my friends have been tagged in, in order to compare the photo I just took to the ones that I've found on facebook.

**MY ASK**

Could you point me to where I can find the policy where it states that I CAN or CANNOT do this?

**JUST TO BE CLEAR**

I'm only comparing and pulling up information for the photo I just took to photos of friends that have been found on FB that I would already have access to.

Thanks for the feedback in advance. This community is awesome and I'm glad to be apart of it.

Long live curiosity.

Pascal

Comment: You just referenced and highlighted the prohibition against developing the kind of application ... and your purchase of Google Glass created a contract where you agreed to abide by the restrictions.   Have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Hey Erstwhilelll, the image I posted is of Google & Google glass.
My question is if Facebook prohibits this.

Comment: SO let me see, you are using Google Glass to take the picture right? (If not, please update your question). Then using some mechanism to try to do a "face match".  The mechanism doesn't matter (Facebook, x, NSA, ...) , it is the operation you have agreed not to pursue with the Google Glass agreement.

Comment: Ok great response!
I am NOT using Google Glass at all. I would be using a phone like an iphone. then doing some sort of face matching. My question is with what database to pull the photos from, originally I was thinking your fb photos (since these would be your fb friends).

Thanks for the help so far Esrtwhilelll

Comment: So your problem domain is to work with an iPhone or Android phone and do the "facial recognition"?  I guess I was thrown off because of the Google-Glass question domain designation.  You might want to read this article referencing facial recognition and Facebook in Germany http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html